# Set of permissions required to add user from DomainA to a group of DomainB with credentials of DomainB

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have two domains (DomainA and DomainB) with a bidirectional domain trust. I have control over Domain B.

I want to add a user from DomainA to a group on DomainB, this is what I'm using:

```
var adminUserOnDomainB ="DomainB\AdminUser";
var passwordOfAdminUserOnDomainB="wowSoMuchSecret";
var userOfDomainAToAdd="TheUserOfDomainA";
var groupOfDomainB="TheGroupOfDomainB";

var domainAContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainA.oneOrganization", adminUserOnDomainB, passwordOfAdminUserOnDomainB);
var domainBContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainB.anotherOrganization", adminUserOnDomainB, passwordOfAdminUserOnDomainB);

var userToAdd = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainAContext, userOfDomainAToAdd);
var groupOnB =  GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainBContext, groupOfDomainB);
groupOnB.Members.Add(userToAdd);
groupOnB.Save();
```

I'm getting "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password." at `groupOnB.Save()`.

If I use an account from DomainA (`var domainAContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainA.oneOrganization", "adminUserOnDomainA", "passwordOfAdminUserOnDomainA");`) I have no problems and everything works fine but I would like to use the same account from DomainB.

Wich set of permissions should I ask to the administrator of DomainA to give to the account from DomainB?

Sadly I don't have a lab env to try and figure out by myself so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that the information being passed to group b is just the username and not a/username where a is group a dimain name

Comment: @Shon already tried with: 
`groupOnB.Members.Add(domainBContext , IdentityType.Name, userToAdd.SamAccountName);
groupOnB.Save(domainBContext );`

it gives an 'NoMatchingPrincipalException: No principal matching the specified parameters was found.' =/

Comment: Not the wanted solution really but in the end I used an account from DomainA and allowed GroubOfDomainB to be managed by that account.